# logger chain in python

Tags: python, logging

I'm writing python package/module and would like the logging messages mention what module/class/function they come from. I.e. if I run this code:

```
import mymodule.utils.worker as worker

w = worker.Worker()
w.run()
```

I'd like to logging messages looks like this:

```
2010-06-07 15:15:29 INFO mymodule.utils.worker.Worker.run <pid/threadid>: Hello from worker
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tend to use the logging module in my packages/modules like so:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info("Whatever your info message.")
```

This sets the name of your logger to the name of the module for inclusion in the log message. You can control where the name is by where `%(name)s` is found in the format string. Similarly you can place the pid with `%(process)d` and the thread id with `%(thread)d`. [See the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) for all the options.

Formatting example:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(process)d/%(threadName)s: %(message)s")
logging.getLogger('this.is.the.module').warning('Testing for SO')
```

Gives me:

```
2010-06-07 08:43:10,494 WARNING this.is.the.module 14980/MainThread: Testing for SO
```

Comment: Yes, I've thought about `__name__`, but it has only the name of the current module, not the full `<package>.<subpackage>.<subsubpackage>.<module>` string. Do you know how can I get such string?

BTW, `%(process)d` is great hint, thanks!

Comment: @Zaar: `__name__` is the full name as imported, not just the last part (assuming the standard import mechanism). Do give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I see it does! Now I'm all set. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution that came out of this discussion. Thanks to everyone for suggestions.

Usage:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> from hierlogger import hierlogger as logger
>>> def main():
...     logger().debug("test")
...
>>> main()
DEBUG:main:test
```

By default it will name logger as ... You can also control the depth by providing parameter:
3 - module.class.method default
2 - module.class
1 - module only

Logger instances are also cached to prevent calculating logger name on each call.
I hope someone will enjoy it.

The code:

```
import logging
import inspect

class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
        def emit(self, record): pass

def hierlogger(level=3):
    callerFrame = inspect.stack()[1]
    caller = callerFrame[0]
    lname = '__heirlogger'+str(level)+'__'
    if lname not in caller.f_locals:
        loggerName = str()
        if level >= 1:
            try:
                loggerName += inspect.getmodule(inspect.stack()[1][0]).__name__
            except: pass
        if 'self' in caller.f_locals and (level >= 2):
            loggerName += ('.' if len(loggerName) > 0 else '') + 
                          caller.f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__
        if callerFrame[3] != '' and level >= 3:
            loggerName += ('.' if len(loggerName) > 0 else '') + callerFrame[3]
        caller.f_locals[lname] = logging.getLogger(loggerName)
        caller.f_locals[lname].addHandler(NullHandler())
    return caller.f_locals[lname]
```

Comment: This code is super useful, saves me a lot of typing during debugging.  Thank you.

Comment: You man deserve to become a saint!
Anyway, I'd like to suggest a few improvements to your code:

- move the return statement one tab back to avoid to return nothing on if failure (but it's probably a format issue)
- remove the NullHandler class definition (you can use logging.NullHandler as well)

Thanks again, very useful code!

Comment: Thanks. "return..." was a formatting error indeed. NullHandler was added to Python 2.7, while this code was written 4 years ago for Python 2.5